# Standardized set of sort icons?

Tags: discussion, icons

Can we (anyone who is interested) create a "standard" set of icons that represent the various sorting methods available? That way, we'll have a set of universally recognized icons.

That means we'll have an icon that represents "newest", "hot", etc.

Anyone that is interested can post their creations as answers.

The images should preferably be in .SVG format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put a few together and you can find them here:

http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/sorting_icons.tar.gz

http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/sorting_preview.png